# Find minimum of nonlinear system of equations with nonlinear equality and inequality constraints in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, constraints, equality, nonlinear-optimization, inequality

I need to solve this problem better described at the title. The idea is that I have two nonlinear equations in four variables, together with two nonlinear inequality constraints. I have discovered that the function `fmincon` is probably the best approach, as you can set everything I require in this situation (please let me know otherwise). However, I'm having some doubts at the implementation stage. Below I'm exposing the complete case, I think it's simple enough to be in its real form.

The first thing I did was to define the objective function in a separate file.

```
function fcns=eqns(x,phi_b,theta_b,l_1,l_2)

fcns=[sin(theta_b)*(x(1)*x(4)-x(2)*x(3))+x(4)*sqrt(x(1)^2+x(2)^2-l_2^2)-x(2)*sqrt(x(3)^2+x(4)^2-l_1^2);
      cos(theta_b)*sin(phi_b)*(x(1)*x(4)-x(2)*x(3))+x(3)*sqrt(x(1)^2+x(2)^2-l_2^2)-x(1)*sqrt(x(3)^2+x(4)^2-l_1^2)];
```

Then the inequality constraints, also in another file.

```
function [c,ceq]=nlinconst(x,phi_b,theta_b,l_1,l_2)

c=[-x(1)^2-x(2)^2+l_2^2; -x(3)^2-x(4)^2+l_1^2];
ceq=[];
```

The next step was to actually run it in a script. Below, since the objective function requires extra variables, I defined an anonymous function `f`. In the next line, I did the same for the constraint (anonymous function). After that, it's pretty self explanatory.

```
f=@(x)norm(eqns(x,phi_b,theta_b,l_1,l_2));
f_c=@(x)nlinconst(x,phi_b,theta_b,l_1,l_2);

x_0=[15 14 16 18],
LB=0.5*[l_2 l_2 l_1 l_1];
UB=1.5*[l_2 l_2 l_1 l_1];

[res,fval]=fmincon(f,x_0,[],[],[],[],LB,UB,f_c),
```

The first thing to notice is that I had to transform my original objective function by the use of `norm`, otherwise I'd get a `"User supplied objective function must return a scalar value."` error message. So, is this the best approach or is there a better way to go around this?

This actually works, but according to my research (one question from stackoverflow actually!) you can guide the optimization procedure if you define an equality constraint from the objective function, which makes sense. I did that through the following code at the constraint file:

```
ceq=eqns(x,phi_b,theta_b,l_1,l_2);
```

After that, I found out I could use the `deal` function and define the constraints within the script.

```
c=@(x)[-x(1)^2-x(2)^2+l_2^2; -x(3)^2-x(4)^2+l_1^2];
f_c=@(x)deal(c(x),f(x));
```

So, which is the best method to do it? Through the constraint file or with this function?

Additionally, I found in MATLAB's documentation that it is suggested in these cases to set:

```
f=@(x)0;
```

Since the original objective function is already at the equality constraints. However, the optimization doesn't go beyond the initial guess obviously (the cost value is already 0 for every solution), which makes sense but leaves me wondering why is it suggested at the documentation (last section here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/nonlinear-systems-with-constraints.html).

Any input will be valued, and sorry for the long text, I like to go into detail if you didn't pick up on it yet... Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `fmincon` is well suited for your problem. Naturally, as with most minimization problems, the objective function is a multivariate *scalar* function. Since you are dealing with a vector function, `fmincon` complained about that.

Is using the norm the "best" approach? The short answer is: it depends. The reason I say this is `norm` in MATLAB is, by default, the Euclidean (or L2) norm and is the most natural choice for most problems. Sometimes however, it may be easier to solve a problem (or more physically meaningful) to use an L1 or a more stringent infinity-norm. I defer a thorough discussion of norms to the following superb blog post: https://rorasa.wordpress.com/2012/05/13/l0-norm-l1-norm-l2-norm-l-infinity-norm/

As for why the example on Mathworks is formulated the way it is: they are solving a system of nonlinear equations - not minimizing a function. They first use the standard approach, using `fsolve`, but then they propose alternate methods of solving the same problem.

One such way is to reformulate solving the nonlinear equations as a minimization problem with an equality constraint. By using `f=@(x)0` with `fmincon`, the objective function `f` is naturally already minimized, and the only thing that has to be satisfied in this case is the equality constraint - which would be the solution to the system of nonlinear equations. Clever indeed.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll check into the L1 vs. L2 norm usage. Well, basically my original problem was just that, a set of two nonlinear equations with four variables. But given it was an underdetermined system I formulated two nonlinear inequality constraints to help solving it. So I actually want to solve that system, but I was forced to make it into a minimization problem. Putting the objective function as an equality constraint was something I thought could help, but has revealed itself not useful since it is satisfied almost from the start. Maybe better constraints or tolerances?

Comment: You should try using fsolve with your inequality constraints and specify the levenberg-marquardt algorithm - it's well suited for that type of problem. Have you been unable to solve the problem? Is it converging to a stationary point? I find that setting `optimset('display', 'iter')` to be immensely helpful in identifying what's going on during the optimization. Also, as pointed out in the mathworks article, you can always improve your chances of solving the system by supplying a bunch of starting guesses.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by using fsolve with the IC. The problem is that fsolve cannot handle constraints at all. Do you mean put the IC as equations and join them with the original two actual equations? If that's what you're suggesting, I assume that algorithm has a way to deal with it, considering the IC are not really equations.
Well, I can get a solution, but it's very dependent on the initial conditions. Apparently it has a bunch of local minima. For the case I'm testing I know the solution, but it doesn't converge unless I start really close.

Comment: Pardon me, I don't know what was going on when I wrote that response. I meant to say, have you tried standard `fsolve` with multiple starting points to see if that is sufficient to solve your problem before you decided to add constraints to help solve it? If yes, then your approach of using `fmincon` to minimize the norm of the objective function with your constraints should be fine. I would use the `f=@(x)0` method as a last resort. In which case you just need your original nonlinear equations as the constraint without the additional constraints you formulated. Hopefully that's clear...

Comment: It's okay, happens to everyone. Eheh
Not really, I assumed from the start that it was necessary to add extra constraints given the number of equations / variables relationship. I'll try these different approaches and see which one is more suited for this particular case. Thank you for all your input, really appreciate it!